# How to make wifi (rt3090) work on ubuntu raring?

Tags: wireless, 13.04, drivers, kernel, ralink

As I can see, one [can](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6078/are-the-ralink-rt3090-drivers-incompatible-with-ubuntu-10-10) [solve](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29984/wireless-not-working-with-a-ralink-rt3090) this problem on earlier versions of `ubuntu`. But there is no packages for `raring` in `ppa:markus-tisoft/rt3090` and it doesn't compile from sources. Also, there is no rt2860sta.ko and rt3090sta.ko in `ubuntu` repositories other than for `lucid`. Have they discontinued support for this device? I can probably use old kernel, but I'd like to find a better solution if any.

Comment: I believe it is covered by the driver rt2800pci in Ubuntu 13.04. Is it loading as expected? lsmod  Is it not working for you?

Comment: The driver is loaded, but it doesn't work.

Comment: "Doesn't work" covers a lot of ground. Does it try to connect and never authenticate? Does it see your network? Are there any informative clues in: dmesg | grep rt2 Is this a laptop with a wireless switch? Please be specific.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know what details I should provide. `dmesg | grep rt2` produces no output, `lsmod | grep rt2` indicates that the driver is loaded (`rt2800pci`). It's a laptop ([hp 620](http://h10010.www1.hp.com/wwpc/ca/en/sm/WF06a/321957-321957-64295-3955548-3955548-4158863.html?dnr=1)). I don't think there is a wireless switch. If I remember correctly, I made it work with older ubuntu without turning on any switches, also the option `Wireless disabled by Hardware switch` is disabled. And it doesn't see any network.

Comment: What does this tell us? rfkill list all Also: sudo modprobe -r rt2800pci && sudo modprobe rt2800pci && dmesg | grep rt2

Comment: I see, it means that wifi is disabled by hardware, the wifi light is red, but I don't know why. Pressing on the button makes no difference. Is it broken? Other devices can see the networks. [rfkill list all](http://sprunge.us/KKfD), `sudo modprobe...` produces no output. I did `rfkill unblock all`, to no avail.

Comment: @x-yuri please read [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/258616/how-can-i-debug-my-wireless-problem) and add the results to your question. Edit your question and add the results inside code sample.

Comment: I figured it out. Wifi doesn't work if already connected to wired network. I've got to disconnect cable first. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The forum appreciates when all questions are answered. I will post an answer that you may accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please be sure the hardware switch is set to enable the wireless radio. Also detach the ethernet cable so that Network Manager will activate the wireless.